How to sign a payload using rsa private key in kotlin
I have an android app that needs to sign a payload using a private key. but I cannot sign my payload with a passphrase.
class AppPrivateKey {

    private fun loadPrivateKey(): RSAPrivateKey {
        val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val keySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(this.getPrivateKey())
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec) as RSAPrivateKey
    }

    fun signPayload(data: String): ByteArray {
        val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
        signature.initSign(this.loadPrivateKey())
        signature.update(data.toByteArray())
        signature.update(env.getRsaPassphrase().toByteArray())
        return signature.sign()
    }

    private fun getPrivateKey(): ByteArray {
        val pem = """-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
// other key content
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"""
        val pemReplaced = pem
            .replace("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace("\n", "")
            .replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(pemReplaced)
    }
}

I developed this code but every time I face a canceled due to java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing private key error. can you please show me how to do it in the right way?

It's not clear what the passphrase has to do with any of this, nor is it clear what line of your code is throwing the exception.

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- points to an encrypted key. You probably need the passphrase for this. Try to import the key by using the passphrase with EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo or BC's PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo, see the examples here and here.

Note that most PEM implementations ignore text outside of the ------- boundaries. Therefore just removing the boundaries and white space chars may not be sufficient. Better limit the data extraction to the part between begin and end block or use an existing PEM parser.
